# CCSlider slow with I-phone/older android

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have recently installed [Cosmocoders CCSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/ccslider-jquery-3d-slideshow-plugin/162445) onto my webpage and I was very impressed with the 3D transitions which when completed will make our site look great...my question is......is there any code or a way to make only the 2D slider load up on older I-phone and android device but the 3D slider still load up on Pc's Mac etc as the page is hardly viewable due to slow down and intense processor usage when viewed on older devices like the I-phone 1?? I would like the best of both worlds if possible....2D slider for older devices and full fledged 3D slider for newer devices and computers.....I hope someone can help me achieve this.

Many Thanks
Andy

My website is [www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk](http://www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk), I may have the 2D slider fade running at the minute as I am still experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a browser detection script like this

```
var effectConfig = {};
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    effectConfig = {
        effectType: '2d',
        effect: 'fadeSlide'
    };
} else {
    effectConfig = {
        effectType: '3d',
        effect: 'cubeUp',
        _3dOptions: {
            imageWidth: 960,
            imageHeight: 400,
            slices: 6,
            depthOffset: 300,
            sliceGap: 50,
            fallBack: 'horizontalWipe',
            delayDir: 'last-first',
            easing: 'easeInOutElastic'
        }
    };
}

var config = jQuery.extend({}, effectConfig, {
    autoPlay: true,
    captions: true,
    controlLinks: false
});

jQuery('#slider').ccslider(config);
```